# We're migrating everything to the cloud - is there a reason to keep Active Directory around?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

We are "cloud-sourcing" all our services (web, databases, file storage, e-mail, print, DNS).

As authentication is made on the could-provider side, I'm wondering about the pro and cons to keep our Active Directory domain controller.

For info, we are a small organization with about 50 users (50/50 laptop-travelers / destop office based).

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/569730/if-a-windows-shop-moves-everything-to-the-cloud-does-it-still-need-active-dir  (I think you inspired TheCleaner to ask this, but it's still a duplicate, IMHO.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you move to some web-based desktop OS, Active Directory still gives you a **significant amount of features related to workstation management** that are unparalleled by any other solution. There are also many 3rd party desktop solutions that benefit greatly from AD, like software deployment. And your cloud solution may even support Kerberos authentication, allowing you to maintain SSO between the computers and cloud.